# Python Multiprocessing Queue Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'put'

Tags: python, multithreading, error-handling, multiprocessing

The code is supposed to derive PI using monte carlo method parallelized across 7 processes.

Here is the first error I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/hirshad/JupyterProjects/ParallelPI/MultiprocessingPI.py
Starting main program
Starting controller
Starting worker Worker-1
Starting worker Worker-2
Starting worker Worker-3
Starting worker Worker-4
Starting worker Worker-5
Starting worker Worker-6
Starting worker Worker-7
Process Worker-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/hirshad/JupyterProjects/ParallelPI/MultiprocessingPI.py", line 24, in run
    self.queue.put(countIn)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'put'
countIn is 76406243
countIn is 76401925
```

The code is

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random as rd


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print("Starting worker " + self.name)
        countIn = 0
        rSquared = 10000
        reach = 100000000
        for iteration in range(reach):
            x = rd.randint(0, 101)
            y = rd.randint(0, 101)
            if ((x * x) + (y * y)) < rSquared:
                countIn += 1

        print("countIn is " + str(countIn))
        self.queue.put(countIn) #ERROR HERE


class Controller(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue
        self.reach = 700000000

    def run(self):
        print("Starting controller")
        workers = []
        countInTotal = 0

        for i in range(7):
            w = Worker(self.queue)
            w.start()
            workers.append(w)
        for i in workers:
            i.join()
        if self.queue.qsize() is not 7:
            print("sleeping for 30 seconds")
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            for i in range(7):
                countInTotal = countInTotal + self.queue.get()
        print("PI is " + str(4*(countInTotal/self.reach)))


if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Starting main program")
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
    c.join()
```

The idea is to use a controller class to manage the workers that will calculate solution parameters in parallel and put to the shared queue. Once the queue reaches desired size of number of workers(7), the controller pops from the queue and sums up the values.

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html, Python's multiprocessing library has a queue object for process to process communication. `self.queue.put(countIn)` should reference the queue object passed by and created by the controller object. The error seems to refer to a function object, but isn't queue a non function object?

EDIT: The issue is in controller class, `self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue`, the Queue class is being passed, not a queue object.

Making a few more bug fixes to make the code work, here is a working solution:

```
import multiprocessing
import random as rd


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print("Starting worker " + self.name)
        countIn = 0
        rSquared = 10000
        reach = 100000000
        for iteration in range(reach):
            x = rd.randint(0, 101)
            y = rd.randint(0, 101)
            if ((x * x) + (y * y)) < rSquared:
                countIn += 1

        print("countIn is " + str(countIn))
        self.queue.put(countIn)


class Controller(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.reach = 700000000

    def run(self):
        print("Starting controller")
        workers = []
        countInTotal = 0

        for i in range(7):
            w = Worker(self.queue)
            w.start()
            workers.append(w)

        for i in workers:
            i.join()

        for i in range(7):
            countInTotal = countInTotal + self.queue.get()

        print("PI is " + str(4*(countInTotal/self.reach)))


if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Starting main program")
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

Comment: Just found the bug. In Controller, self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue should be an initializer not the class: self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(). Please feel free to answer as solution and any other suggestions for improvement.